# mailto - link not launching on iOS Web App

Tags: html, ios, mailto

I am designing a Web App in dreamweaver so using html code etc. I have got the telephone link now to work using a 
But I am struggling on my iPhone App to get the mailto link to work for email link

When I press the link  nothing happens ( all works find on web browser) and on my iPhone App, the Mail does not load up.

I have look everywhere and can find the solution.

```
<a href='#' onclick='window.open(`mailto:test@test.co.uk`, `_self`);'>Link text</a>
```

I found this code on stack overflow but its over 8years old and does not work?

Hope you can help?

Tim

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<p><a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a></p>
```

It makes use of href.

Comment: This is the exact same answer as I gave... Strange...

Answer (score 0):

If it is to "hide" the email, then change to

```
<a href='#' onclick='this.href=`mailto:test@test.co.uk`'>Link text</a>
```

otherwise

```
<a href='mailto:test@test.co.uk'>Link text</a>
```

Comment: Thank for replay but this works fine on a web browser but not on a html App with uses a iframe to display the html website.
As I said I have got the phone to work just not the email link

The code you stated does not work, nothing happens at all in the APP

There has to be a solution?? Its silly. 

If I hold down one the link a popup menu appears and then there is a options called

“New Mail Message’ 

But not via the link to load up the iOS mail system

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mailto+ios+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution to the issue and that is to add  target="_blank" and this then open Mail on a iPhone APP and all is fine. For some reason this is not stated on any other fourm not sure why ;-( a bit simple really